# Override an [abstract baseclass property] in a [abstract class] with a [derived-from-baseclass-property] in an inherrited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm confused by different inherritance/abstraction interactions.
Lets say I have a certain class called `BaseClass`, now on this baseclass I have multiple inherrited derived classes, `InherritedBaseClassA` etc..

```
class BaseClass
{
    int SomeGenericProperties {get; set;}    
}
class InherritedBaseClassA : BaseClass
{
    int PropertyOnlyInA {get; set;}
}
class InherritedBaseClassB : BaseClass
{
    int PropertyOnlyInB {get; set;}
}
```

Now I would like to add this `BaseClass` as a property into an `abstract` class:

```
abstract class AbstractBase
{
   public abstract Baseclass MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

and finally, I would like, In my implementation of this `abstract` class, to override this `BaseClass` with `Derived` classes.

```
class Implementation_A_OfAbstractBase : AbstractBase
{
    // how do i write this line?
    public override InherritedBaseClassA MyProperty;
}
```

I want to do this because elsewhere in my code I have a generic list of `AbstractBase` and sometimes I want to acces `AbstractBase.MyProperty.SomeGenericProperties` which exist no matter what kind of inherrited baseclass implementation im using since their `MyProperty` is inherrited from `BaseClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to use C# Generics to solve this problem.

A quick implementation would look like this:

```
abstract class AbstractBase<T> where T: Baseclass
{
    public abstract T MyProperty { get; set;}
}

class Implementation_A_OfAbstractBase : AbstractBase<InherritedBaseClassA>         
{
    //you no longer need to override the property, the generic type takes care of this for you.
}
```

It is important to note the `where T: Baseclass` this is going to tell the compiler that the type specified will always inherit `Baseclass` and compilation will actually fail if you try to use a type that does not.

Also [here is some additional reading on generics.](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20generics)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use generics for that.

For example:

```
abstract class AbstractBase<T>
    where T : BaseClass
{
    public abstract T MyProperty { get; set; }
}

abstract class AbstractBase : AbstractBase<BaseClass>
{
}

class Implementation_A_OfAbstractBase : AbstractBase<InherritedBaseClassA>
{
    public override InherritedBaseClassA MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```